# Targetting parent element with js

Tags: javascript

I want to change the parent element of my span if the  span has a class.

I tried to make a function but it doesn't work. can someone tell me how to do it ?

```js
var parent = deswpanspan.parentElement;
document.querySelectorAll(".spanss").forEach(function(deswpanspan) {
  if (deswpanspan.classList.contains("Dnone")) {
    parent.classlist.add("Dnone");
  } else {
    deswpanspan.classList.add("failed");
  }
})
```

```html
<p class="ContRowBorderLeftp"><span class="spanss Dnone"></span> </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had spelling mistakes and parent outside the forEach

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".spanss").forEach(function(span) {
  const parent = span.closest(".ContRowBorderLeftp")
  if (span.classList.contains("Dnone")) {
    parent.classList.add("Dnone");
  } else {
    span.classList.add("failed");
  }
})
```

```css
.Dnone {
  color: green
}

.failed {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<p class="ContRowBorderLeftp">Parent <span class="spanss Dnone">Span with Dnone</span> </p>

<p class="ContRowBorderLeftp">Parent <span class="spanss">Failed Span</span> </p>
```

Comment: Thank you your solution works. I was so focused on using the parentElement that I didn't even think about using the closest to achieve the same result.

Comment: You COULD have used parentElement, but not where you did